# About selling things online

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, internet

Can I sell my themes (used in websites) online?

I am confused, because it can be used for bad websites like movies, music, porn, etc. and can also be used for good things. Someone said to me that it not a sin to sell it if you don't know what the purchaser is going to do with it then we should ask every user that why he or she is purchasing my themes.

Answer (score 3):

The themes are general parts of almost every website. So if you sell them and anyone mis-use them, there is no sin on you for this.

Take the example of a knife maker. Some people use a knife to kill; does that mean knife making is a sin? And should not be made at all? Of course not. So you can sell those themses without any worries to think that they could be a sin.